# Spring: passing data between server and client (Java objects to JS objects)

Tags: javascript, spring, extjs

I want to implement transparent data passing between my server (using Spring) and client (in ExtJS).

On the server side I have Spring Controllers returning ModelAndView objects (using JSPs). I usually don't create model objects, I just put items into a model Map.

I want easy transparent Java to Javascript object conversion. On the server side I put a Java Date object into the map and I get a Javascript Date object on the client. 
I.e. on the server I write such code:

```
public ModelAndView getModelAndView(User user) {
    Map<String, Object> modelMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    modelMap.put("date", new Date());
    modelMap.put("intarray", new int[] {1,2,3});
    return new ModelAndView("mainpage", modelMap);
}
```

and on the client I write in JSP:

```
var model = <someMagicTagOrSomething />
```

and in the rendered HTML I get:

```
var model = {
     date: Date.parse('2012-01-01 12:12:12', 'Y-m-d H:m:s'), //JS Date object
     intarray: [1,2,3]
}
```

Most of what I've seen in the Spring documentation involves specifying object formatting on the server using annotations like @NumberFormat(style=Style.PERCENT) and then getting them on the client using form:input tags. This is not something I want, because I want to format date on the client and not worry about in what format they're transmitted to the client.

What's the best way to accomplish this? Is there an out-of-the-box solution or do I need to write something myself? I know I can use a library like Gson to translate my model into JSON, but this returns the Java Dates as strings and I'd like to get Javascript date objects right away and not have to worry about formatting.

Thanks for any advice,

Piotr

Answer (score 1):

You won't avoid serializing dates to some format. Javascript doesn't understand java objects so there has to be some serialization step (be it json, xml or whatever).

Your best shot is to send dates as `ISO` strings and use `Date.parse(isostring)` on them. You don't need to specify the format string then, so you have to type less and at least you work with format most clients understand.

Comment: I understand that I have to serialize/deserialize objects somehow. I would just prefer to have it done transparently/automatically for me. In the solution you're proposing I would need for every date to add "Date.parse" in Javascript. I'd like the server to add these "Date.parse" invocations for me. So instead of the server gluing JSON into the HTML when rendering JSP it would glue a combination of Javascript and JSON that would eventually create regular JS objects (like in the example from my question). Is there perhaps some library or Spring mechanism that does this?

Comment: @machinery That's IMO out of spring scope, but there are extensions for popular js libraries that do automatic date-string to javascript date conversion ([example for jquery](http://erraticdev.blogspot.com.es/2010/12/converting-dates-in-json-strings-using.html), didn't test it).

Answer (score 0):

```
<c:set var="myModelObject" value="${myObjectFromServer}"/>

 <script>
   var myJSvar = "${myModelObject}";
 </script>
```

And yeah, you'll have to serialize/deserialize dates ... I extend the PropertyEditor :

```
public class LocalDateEditor extends PropertyEditorSupport{
    @Override
    public void setAsText(String text) throws IllegalArgumentException{
        setValue(DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd MMM yyyy").print(text));
    }
```

and then register that in yr controller (you can also set a global one, but I can't remember how) :

```
@InitBinder
protected void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    binder.registerCustomEditor(LocalDate.class, new LocalDateEditor());
}
```

for what its worth I use a global date formatter, and on the user interface a global jquery ui datepicker class - not much coding required at all really. And everything works out of the box - after the initial set up. I never liked the iso standard dates (that might be because I am british :-( )

Comment: But this will get rendered to something like this, right? var myJSvar = "12 Mar 2012"; Please see my comment to soulcheck's answer. Thanks :)

Comment: thats exactly what it will do. Sounds like you want the server to create the client code for you - which sound slike a bad idea imho. You are mixing controller with view (the V and C, from MVC).  GWT and Vaadin remove the need to write javascript.

Comment: Hmm.. I'm not against writing some Javascript, but thanks for the tip. I think in my case the view and controller mixing is justified. It would allow me to drop a bit of boilerplate code.